# interface of childViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have my ViewController, and 3 another Controllers, I wanna put them into my ViewController.

Here is a code, where I am making childViewControllers and adding them. With different colors, to see am I right with counting frames.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    EnterAndLogViewController *EALViewController = [[EnterAndLogViewController alloc]init];
    SentPacksViewController *SPViewController = [[SentPacksViewController alloc]init];
    RecievedPacksViewController *RPViewController = [[RecievedPacksViewController alloc]init];

    [self makeChildViewController:EALViewController];
    [self makeSizeOfEALViewController:EALViewController];

    [self makeChildViewController:SPViewController];
    [self makeSizeOfSPViewController:SPViewController];

    [self makeChildViewController:RPViewController];
    [self makeSizeOfRPViewController:RPViewController];




}

- (UIColor *)makeColor
{
    CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 );  //  0.0 to 1.0
    CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from white
    CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from black
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];\
    return color;
}


- (void) makeChildViewController:(UIViewController *) controller
{
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}

- (void) makeSizeOfEALViewController: (EnterAndLogViewController *) controller
{
    CGRect myFrame=CGRectMake(20.0f, 20.0f,self.view.bounds.size.width - 40.0f , (self.view.bounds.size.height - 40.0f)/2.0f);
    controller.view.frame = myFrame;
    //controller.view.backgroundColor = [self makeColor];
}

- (void)makeSizeOfSPViewController : (SentPacksViewController *) controller
{
    CGRect myFrame=CGRectMake(20.0f, (self.view.bounds.size.height - 40.0f)/2.0f +20 , (self.view.bounds.size.width- 40.0f)/2 , (self.view.bounds.size.height - 40.0f)/2.0f);
    controller.view.frame = myFrame;
    controller.view.backgroundColor = [self makeColor];

}

- (void) makeSizeOfRPViewController : (RecievedPacksViewController *) controller
{
    CGRect myFrame=CGRectMake(20.0f + (self.view.bounds.size.width- 40.0f)/2 , (self.view.bounds.size.height - 40.0f)/2.0f +20 , (self.view.bounds.size.width- 40.0f)/2 , (self.view.bounds.size.height - 40.0f)/2.0f);
    controller.view.frame = myFrame;
    controller.view.backgroundColor = [self makeColor];


}
```

In my Storyboard I have 1 controller ( ViewController ) and 3 another my ViewControllers. But when I adding some UI to this controllers, on my main ViewController they aren't show.

example : I am adding a button to my EnterAndLogViewController in storyboard, making outlet and action, but this button isn't show in my main ViewController.

Why? Can You help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use alloc/init to create view controllers. If you do that the views for the view controller don't get loaded. If the view controllers are defined in your storyboard, use the storyboard method `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` (you'll need to set a unique identifier on each of your scenes in your storyboard.

The code might look like this:

```
EnterAndLogViewController *EALViewController = 
  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"EnterAndLogViewController"];
```

(That's assuming that you set up that view controller's scene in IB with the unique identifier "EnterAndLogViewController")

You can then install that view controller as a child view controller.

Note that with recent versions of iOS you can set up a container view in your parent view controller and link up an "embed segue" to do this for you automatically. That does all the housekeeping for you, and lets you define the frame for your child view controllers easily.

Comment: It works, thank you. I forgot about this method, it is obviously. Now I understand how to do this.

I want to do in this way, thank you for your time!